# Small question about $\mathring{A}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have a small question on topology, I have a space $E$ with this topology $$\theta=\{G\subseteq E, \mathrm{card}(E\setminus G)<\infty\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$$
such that $\mathrm{card}(E)=\infty$

I want to find $\mathring{A}$ where $\mathrm{card}(A)=\infty$ and $\mathrm{card}(E\setminus A)=\infty$.

Comment: Since $\mathring{A}$ is open, it's either $\emptyset$ or it's (infinite and) cofinite. Because $\mathring{A} \subseteq A$, the complement of $\mathring{A}$ contains the complement of $A$, which is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be an open set contained in $A$; if $U\ne\emptyset$, then $E\setminus U$ is finite. However, from $U\subseteq A$ it follows $E\setminus U\supseteq E\setminus A$. Hence…

Comment: @Vrouvrou You're welcome! While the cofinite topology seems rather dull, it can be used for several examples and counterexamples as well as for proving that Tykhonov's theorem is equivalent to the axiom of choice.